# array putting random numbers based on size

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

```
cout << "Enter Array size: ";
cin >> size;

while(size < 5){
    cout << "Invalid value. N must be greater than five(5)" << endl;
    cout << "Enter array size: ";
    cin >> size;
    }
    

int array[size]; 


for(int num=0; num < size; num++){
    
    cout << "Enter value for index " << num << ": ";
    cin >> temp; 

    
    
    bool found = false;
    for(i=0; i < num; i++){
        if(array[i] == temp){   
            found = true;
            }
        }
        
    if (found){
        cout << "Already entered!" << endl;
        num -- ;
        }
    else{
        array[num] = temp;
        
        
        for (k=0; k<size; k++){
            for(j=k+1; j<size; j++){
                
                if(array[j] > array[k]){
                    o = array[k];
                    array[k] = array[j];
                    array[j] = o;
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        cout << "Values: ";
        for(int num2=0; num2<num; num2++){
            cout << array[num2] << " ";
            
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
    
    }

return 0;
}
```

My code gives me random numbers based on its size for some reason and im stuck on what to do on it. Example

Enter Array size: 5

Enter value for index 0: 3

Values:

Enter value for index 1: 6

Values: 32

Enter value for index 2: 2

Values: 32 6

Enter value for index 3: 5

Values: 32 6 5

Enter value for index 4: 3

Values: 32 6 5 3

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: You only have `num` valid elements but you're sorting `size` elements.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cin >> size;
> // ...
> int array[size];
> ```

This is not allowed in C++. The size of an array variable must be compile time constant. In order to create an array with dynamic  size, you must use dynamic storage. Most convenient way to do that is to use `std::vector`.

---

```
    for (k=0; k<size; k++){
        for(j=k+1; j<size; j++){
            
            if(array[j] > array[k]){
                o = array[k];
                array[k] = array[j];
                array[j] = o;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, you appear to be attempting to sort the array. But in first iteration, all elements except the first are uninitialised. You read indeterminate values and the behaviour of the program is undefined.